# Error Accessing Image using create post from admin

Tags: php, html, laravel, image, web

I am having a problem with accessing images
I tried accessing image at public/storage/images with database seeder, and it works well
like this:

[image: image using database seeder]

but if i try accessing image using "create post from admin", it didn't work.
like this:

[image: image using create post from admin]

this my code:

**PostController.php**

```
public function store(){
        $inputs = request()->validate([
            'title'=>'required|min:8|max:255',
            'post_image'=>'file', //mime: jpeg, png
            'body'=>'required'
        ]);
        if(request('post_image')){
            $inputs['post_image'] = request('post_image')->store('images');
        }
        auth()->user()->posts()->create($inputs);
        return back();
}
```

**blog-home.blade.php**

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
    <div class="card mb-4">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="{{($post->post_image)}}" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
        <h2 class="card-title">{{$post->title}}</h2>
        <p class="card-text">{{Str::limit($post->body, '50', '....')}}</p>
        <a href="{{route('post', $post->id)}}" class="btn btn-primary">Read More &rarr;</a>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer text-muted">
        Posted on {{$post->created_at->diffForHumans()}} by
        <a href="#">{{$post->name}}</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
```

**web.php (routes)**

```
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
Route::get('/post/{post}', [App\Http\Controllers\PostController::class, 'show'])->name('post');    

Route::middleware('auth')->group(function(){
    Route::get('/admin', [App\Http\Controllers\AdminController::class, 'index'])->name('admin.index');

    Route::get('/admin/posts', [App\Http\Controllers\PostController::class, 'index'])->name('post.index');
    Route::get('/admin/posts/create', [App\Http\Controllers\PostController::class, 'create'])->name('post.create');
    Route::post('/admin/posts', [App\Http\Controllers\PostController::class, 'store'])->name('post.store');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember to create a symbolic link from public/storage to storage/app/public.

to make a symbolic link run:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

And change your image tag src tp

```php
  <img class="card-img-top" src="{{url('storage/'.$post->post_image)}}" alt="Card image cap">
```